# How to fix Proxy server error on Windows 10?

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, proxy

I ran into a proxy problem in my package.json file.

```
"dev": "set PROXY = true && node server.js",
"dev-saas": "set PROXY = true && node server.js",
```

On Windows, this code does not start the program and gives an error

> 'PROXY' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

After doing a little google search, I changed the code to this

```
  "dev": "set PROXY = true && node server.js",
  "dev-saas": "set PROXY = true && node server.js",
```

and wrote a little below:

```
  "proxy": {
    "target": "http: // localhost: 3001"
  },
```

After that, the code works, but I don't think it's correct, because it gives an error:

> Error: [HPM] Missing "target" option. Example: {target: "http://www.example.org/%22%7D

Comment: What are you trying to do with "set PROXY = true"? Because typically, one sets a combination of `http_proxy`, `https_proxy`, and `no_proxy` in various cases to set proxy information. You're apparently using this for some kind of application (`[HPM]`)?